# Set selected item from combobox to textfield

Tags: javafx

I want to set the text of a TextField depending of the selected Item in the ComboBox

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to rewrite the question. Currently it's impossible to tell what your exact requirements are. (E.g. there is at most a single value selected in a `ComboBox`/`ChoiceBox`, you didn't describe what exactly your problem is with setting the `TextField` text and why you need to do this at all (`ComboBox`/`ChoiceBox` display the chosen item))

Comment: I want to set values into a TextField when selecting an Item from a Combobox for example in Javafx I try to write my code like this:personneList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
 personnelcongetxt.setText(String.valueOf(personneList.getValue())); and it  give me null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want to set the text of a `TextField` depending of the selected Item in the `ComboBox`. Probably you are simply using as you mentioned in a comment: `personnelcongetxt.setText(String.valueOf(personneList.getValue()));` which won't update your value every time you select a different item. It is always null since the default selection(if you didn't set) is null, so it 'prints' null in the `Textfield` . If you want to be updated there are two ways:

1. Using bindings.
2. Using listener.

Here is the code:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Model> cb;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        initCB();
        // Solution one : using bindings :
        tf.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull())
                .then("")
                .otherwise(cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().asString())); // uses toString of the Model

        // Solution two using listener :
//      cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
//          tf.setText(newValue.toString()); // or newValue.getName();
//      });
    }

    private void initCB() {
        cb.setItems(FXCollections
                .observableArrayList(new Model("Apple"), new Model("Banana"), new Model("")));
    }

    private class Model {
        private String name;

        public Model(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

}
```

Depending on your choice the result may be a little bit different.

- If you are using the first solution(bindings) then you won't be able to change 'manually' by typing the text of the textfield, but you can be sure that the `TextField` shows every time the selected item of the combobox.
- If you are using the second solution(listener), then the value of the textField is updated after you select a new item, but after that it lets you edit the textfield at any time and you can change the text to any string. So if you want this functionality then you should go this way.

Long story short: bindings show always the selected item, listener shows only after selecting a new item.

Comment: Thanks for you help :)